# Numba compatibility with numpy.random.binomial

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numba

I was trying to use numba to speed up a portion of my code that generates an array of Bernoulli random variables according to an array of success probability. It is something along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def Bernoulli(a, b, c):
    prob = np.array from some calculation to a, b and c
    accepted = np.random.binomial(1, prob)
    return accepted

Bernoulli(a, b, c)
```

However, this error code occurs:

```
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'Numpy_negative_binomial.generic': File: numba\core\typing\randomdecl.py: Line 171.
    With argument(s): '(int64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match for registered cases:
    * (int64, float64) -> int64
```

I understand this as the current numba implementation does not support an array of success probability as argument for np.random.binomial. Is this correct? 
If so, is this implementation an efficient workaround for the problem?

```
@njit(parallel = True)
def Bernoulli(a, b, c):
    prob = np.array from some calculation to a, b and c
    accepted = np.zeros(N)
    for i in prange(N):
        accepted[i] = np.random.binomial(1, prob[i])
    return accepted
```

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2640

Comment: Ok so array as input really isn't supported. Do you think my workaround method is appropriate or are there methods that are more efficient?

Comment: An alternative without requiring paralelization might be to do a random uniform `random_probability = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=1,size=prob.shape)` and then use entrywise comparison:  `accepted = random_probability < prob`.